# Background uploading concerns (objective c)

Tags: objective-c, ios7, background-process

We are working on one iOS application that needs to upload photos, videos to **amazon s3**. We need to do below tasks for this application:

1. Upload video, image in the background
2. If network connection is lost, alert the user
3. If user has low signal, give a message to the user for trying this upload later (we are storing all upload files in local till it we complete upload)

We are using `NSURLRequest` for uploading all files in the background. But we are not sure if this is the correct approach because it has lot of issues. Can someone recommend best approach and methods to use in iOS for above tasks.

Answer (score 0):

thats fine if you want to support ios6 as well -- for ios7+ switch to NSURLSession

beware though that iOS does not guarantee background time and may cancel your process at any time

to check for that, register a backgroundHandler which offers an expiry block that is called before the os does kill your process

1. tell os you want to run a bg task:

   ```
   UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier token = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
       NSLog(@"Ranging for region %@ killed", region.identifier);
   }];
   if(token == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
       NSLog(@"cant start background task");
   }
   ```
2. do whatever you want to do ..
3. when done, tell os:

   ```
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:token];
   ```

Note: this rarely works indefinitely and it meant to be used that way. The OS can still decide to kill you! (chances for your app to run a longer time are better if you don't use much memory and as little cpu / bandwidth as possible)

---

regarding your use case:

if your NSURLConnection fails your completionBlock or the delegate gets an error.

you can show a UILocalNotification then

dummy code using blocks:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                                                  NSData *data,
                                                 NSError *connectionError) {
    if(connectionError) {
        UILocalNotification *theNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        theNotification.alertBody = connectionError.description;
        theNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:theNotification];
    }
}];
```

Comment: Thank you for the instant response. But we face some issues here.. If the user suddenly loss network connection, we want to flash a message saying that "upload has failed".. Also how to check the signal strength.

Comment: added that bit as well

Comment: Thank you...But how to check the strength of the signal..For instance, if the user has a very low network, we don't want to upload the file...Is that possible?

Comment: well you check if he has Wifi / 3g / edge / nothing... is that what you want?

Comment: not actually..cellular network is also fine..but if the signal strength is too low, we dont want the user to upload

Comment: getting the extact bandwidth would require you to do speed tests by uploading a few bytes and measuring the time that takes

Comment: We had thought about uploading few bytes method, but we were worried whether that is the correct method and we also though it would create unnecessary overhead

Comment: ;) you're out of options then AFAICS